How do you cancel a long-running MySQL query via JDBC?
I have a long-running query that I run against a MySQL 8 database via JDBC. My goal is to be able to exit this query on some trigger (e.g. external signal, data processing error, etc.) and have the query cancel. Based on my tests and research on MySQL forums, the statement.cancel() does not actually do anything.
How can I achieve this? Is there no other way than to invoke KILL <pid> on a separate connection? If so, I can manage that, but I don't understand how I can identify the exact PID of my long-running query. Is there a reliable method for this?
In short, how can I, using MySQL Connector J, cancel a long-running query on demand? I would really appreciate a link to a working example with code, if at all possible.
For reference, here is some sample code written in Kotlin:
val data = produce<List<Data>> {
    db.connection.use { conn ->
        conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).use { stmt ->
            stmt.fetchSize = Int.MIN_VALUE
            stmt.executeQuery("...").use { rs ->
                var batch = mutableListOf<Data>()
                while (rs.next()) {
                    // Handle result set here
                    val data = Data(
                        id = rs.getLong("id"),
                        subAccountId = rs.getInt("sub_account_id")
                    )
                    batch.add(data)
                    if (batch.size >= 100) {
                        println("Sending batch...")
                        send(batch)
                        if (done) {
                            println("Done, closing...")
                            close()
                            break
                        }
                        batch = mutableListOf()
                    }
                }
                println("Out of loop, cancelling statement")
                synchronized(this) { // my lame attempt at cancelling
                    println("In synchronized")
                    if (!stmt.isClosed) {
                        println("Statement is not yet closed") // DOES print
                        stmt.cancel()
                        stmt.close()
                        conn.close() // probably pointless but I tried
                    }
                }
            }
            println("Out of statement") // does NOT print
        }
        println("Out of connection") // does NOT print
    }
    println("End of production...") // does NOT print
}

I'm able to see up through "Statement is not yet closed" in the console, but nothing beyond that.
EDIT:
I came across this forum discussion and after some messing around, I came up with this code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class, DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
fun dbSqlKillTestWithCoroutines() {
    runBlocking {
        db.connection.use { conn ->
            conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).use { stmt ->
                stmt.fetchSize = Int.MIN_VALUE

                // Get connection ID
                val connectionId = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT CONNECTION_ID()").use { rs ->
                    rs.next()
                    rs.getString(1)
                }

                // Produce data
                val data = produce<List<Data>>(Dispatchers.IO) { // Dispatchers.IO is not necessary for query to be killed
                    stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ...").use { rs -> // omitted SQL
                        var batch = mutableListOf<Data>()
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            val data = Data(...) // omitted mapper
                            batch.add(data)
                            if (batch.size >= 100) {
                                println("Sending batch")
                                send(batch)
                                batch = mutableListOf()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Consume data
                var count = 0
                for (batch in data) {
                    count++
                    println("Received batch $count")
                    if (count >= 3) {
                        println("Attempting to cancel query...")

                        println("Breaking...")
                        break
                    }
                }

                // Method 3, no new thread at all
//                println("Breaking in same context...")
//                db.connection.use { conn2 ->
////                        conn2.catalog = "information_schema"
////                        conn2.autoCommit = true
//                    conn2.createStatement().use { stmt2 ->
//                        stmt2.execute("KILL QUERY $connectionId")
//                    }
//                }

                // Method 2, use coroutines to create Thread
//                newSingleThreadContext("ctx").use { ctx ->
//                    launch(ctx) {
//                        println("Breaking in single thread context...")
//                        db.connection.use { conn2 ->
////                        conn2.catalog = "information_schema"
////                        conn2.autoCommit = true
//                            conn2.createStatement().use { stmt2 ->
//                                stmt2.execute("KILL QUERY $connectionId")
//                            }
//                        }
//                    }
//                }

                // Method 1, create raw Thread() instance manually
                thread(true) {
                    println("Breaking in thread...")
                    db.connection.use { conn2 ->
//                        conn2.catalog = "information_schema"
//                        conn2.autoCommit = true
                        conn2.createStatement().use { stmt2 ->
                            stmt2.execute("KILL QUERY $connectionId")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

All 3 methods seemed to work in my test. I had read elsewhere that you need to call KILL QUERY on a separate thread, however the success of "method 3" above tells me that wasn't actually the case (or that it's working for me because of some special condition I'm not aware of).
In short, this code seems to work, so I'll be using it for my purposes. My goal is to run a long-running SELECT query (one that could take a week or longer to complete) and process the data as it comes in so as to not consume too much memory (would be many gigabytes of memory otherwise). I then want to be ready to address any errors that occur in the processing by stopping the query and processing. In my case, I can stop at any point and pick back up where I left off and not have to restart the query from scratch.
If anyone more knowledgeable can come along and give input on how to make it better/more bullet-proof, I would personally appreciate it.

(1) use staement  void cancel()
stmt.execute(sqlQuery); ,  stmt.cancel(); (2)  You can set the query limit time before executing the query. Statement.setQueryTimeout(int seconds) (3) Api docs: "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html"

@life888888 um, as I mentioned in my post, stmt.cancel() does not do anything with MySQL Connector J. Query timeout is also not acceptable in this situation (however query timeouts do work with MySQL).

KILL doesn't guarantee to terminate the query either. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78386621/20860
